# How to configure locale aliases using i18n & rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n

I am working on a rails app (3.2.13) that is being translated into several languages, including (one of the 3 available flavours of) Norwegian. On public pages, the app uses the browser's language settings to set locale.

Most browsers offer 3 separate Norwegian shortcodes: `no`, `nb` & `nn`. The translations we have are in `nb`, but I think it would be best if `no` & `nn` also defaulted to `nb`. That way, if a user's browser language preferences were set to `no` then `en`, the app would try to supply `nb` Norwegian first, instead of skipping straight to English.

Is it possible to configure a list of "language aliases" for the i18n gem, something like this?

```
 config.i18n.available_locales = [:sv, :en, :nb, :da, :fi]
 config.i18n.aliased_locales = [:nb <= :no, :nb <= :nn]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer**

Take a look to the fallbacks

Create a file in `initializers` like `i18n_fallbacks.rb`

```
config.i18n.fallbacks = {:no => [:nb], :nn => [:nb]}
```

[Here the reference](http://batsov.com/articles/2012/09/12/setting-up-fallback-locale-s-in-rails-3/)

**Things related**

You can even set multiple fallbacks, and they will be taken in the same order as specified:

for instance:

```
config.i18n.default_locale = :de
config.i18n.fallbacks = {:de => [:en,:es]}
```

**de.yml**

```
  :de:
    greeting: Hallo
```

**en.yml**

```
  :en:
    foo: bar
```

**es.yml**

```
  :es:
    bar: baz
```

You get the following:

```
I18n.t :greeting # found in de.yml, no fallback
# => 'Hallo'

I18n.t :foo # not in :de, try in :en and found
# => "bar"

I18n.t :bar # not in :de, try in :en and in :es
# => "baz"

I81n.t :other # not found anywhere, note the message delivers not found for the current locale:
# => "translation missing: de.other"
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer & examples. I have a follow-up question, in case you would like to take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28328085/i18n-locale-disregarding-fallbacks

Answer (score 0):

In latest i18n gem (0.7.0) I have found it necessary to define fallback locales like this (in `config/application.rb`):

```
# Custom I18n fallbacks
config.after_initialize do
  I18n.fallbacks = I18n::Locale::Fallbacks.new(at: :"de-DE", ch: :"de-DE", gb: :"en-US")
end
```

You also need to set `config.i18n.fallbacks = true` in all `config/environments/*.rb` files.